# Calling a Perl hash function

Tags: perl

How do you call a function from a hash value?

```
%hash = { "1" => \&some_function } ; # this function has one parameter
sub some_function {
  my $arg = $_[0];
  return $arg;
}
$hash{"1"}->($arg); <-- tried this but doesn't work.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`%hash` is a hash. `{ "1" => \&some_function }` is a hash reference.
You need one of the following variants:

```
$hash = { "1" => \&some_function };
$hash->{"1"}->($arg);
```

or

```
%hash = ( "1" => \&some_function );
$hash{"1"}->($arg);
```

See [perldata](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.30.0/perldata.html#List-value-constructors) and [perlref](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.30.0/perlref.html) for details.

Comment: Note that `%hash = { "1" => \&some_function }` will produce a "Reference found where even-sized list expected" warning.  warnings will help you avoid many coding errors; make sure you have them enabled

Answer (score 4):

To declare a hash, use round parentheses. Curly braces are for hash references / anonymous hashes.

```
%hash = ( 1 => \&some_function );
sub some_function {
    my $arg = $_[0];
    return $arg
}
$hash{1}($arg);
```